# How to output $variables without loading everything?

Tags: 7, debugging

I'm trying to debug a drupal 7 site and print_r() the $variables variable, but its HUGE and crashes certain pages when there is alot of data in it. Is there a way to only output the first level of the array without outputting everything inside of it?

Answer (score 1):

[Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) is a great tool for debugging. It comes with `krumo()` function which works similar to `print_r()` but doesn't output everything, only up to certain depth (I think 3 or 4 levels).

Comment: i know about devel, but what if I didn't want to use that. how can I do it in pure php? is there a special function for it?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue and found a raw solution, not very elegant nor easily usable in all cases, but it might help you:

1. First use `print_r(array_keys($variables))`.
2. Look at the result to locate which keys match your needs.
3. Then for each one, say `$var_x`, use `print_r($variables[$var_x])`
4. And if it's too heavy again, go to #1 replacing `$variables` by `$variables[$var_x])`... and so on!